# How to insert multiple records from one table into another on update of third table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm having difficulty with developing the logic in MySQL. I don't know how to INSERT multiple records from a Table AFTER UPDATE.

```
CREATE TABLE primeira(
ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
nome varchar(30) NOT NULL,
valor int DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE segunda(
ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID_primeira int,
ultimo_valor int DEFAULT 0,
credito int NOT NULL,
limite int DEFAULT 0,
FOREIGN KEY(ID_primeira) references primeira(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE terceira(
ID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID_segunda int,
`data` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
estado boolean DEFAULT false,
FOREIGN KEY(ID_segunda) references segunda(ID)
);

CREATE TRIGGER tr_segundaLimite_INS
BEFORE INSERT ON segunda FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.limite = New.ultimo_valor + New.credito;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_primeira_UPD 
AFTER UPDATE ON primeira FOR EACH ROW      
   IF (SELECT limite FROM segunda WHERE segunda.ID_primeira = New.ID AND 
       (limite - NEW.valor)< 50) THEN
        INSERT INTO terceira(ID_segunda)            
        VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM segunda WHERE segunda.ID_primeira = New.ID 
        AND (limite - NEW.valor)< 50));
   END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm going to use procedures with functions to SELECT the data. The problem with this TRIGGER is that it's not working when there are multiple matching records.

The error that I am getting is-

```
subquery returns more than 1 row.
```

The objective is: After an update of the `primeira.valor`, the trigger would subtract `segunda.limite - New.valor`. If this difference is < 50 then all the matching `segunda.ID` would be registered at `terceira.ID_segunda` on `terceira` table.

I'm using data below:

```
INSERT INTO primeira(nome,valor)
VALUES 
('Burro',800),
('Chiconizio',300),
('Xerosque',400),
('Shrek',600);

INSERT INTO segunda(ID_primeira,ultimo_valor,credito)
VALUES 
(1,600,800),
(1,700,400),
(1,800,500),
(2,150,200),
(2,200,180),
(2,250,300);

UPDATE primeira 
SET Valor = 330
WHERE ID = 2;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Clearly explain what you have tried so far and why it didn't work. (I tried X, I expected Y but instead Z happened). Clearly explain your problem with correct grammar. "he can't work if he match with more than one value" doesn't make much sense. Include the exact error message or example. Limit your post to a single clear question. Remove question about whether to use PHP or MySQL as this is primarily opinion based (such questions doesn't belong on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Didimo: Please share structures of the involved tables and a bit description of what you exactly want to do with this trigger.

Comment: @HannesLandeholm Really thanks for the patience, and thanks for the welcome.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal Oh sure! Sorry, updated.

Comment: Do you want to calculate- `New.valor - segunda.limite` or `segunda.limite - NEW.valor` ? You have written `New.valor - segunda.limite` in your description, but in trigger code you are trying to do `segunda.limite - NEW.valor`. Please confirm this thing.

Comment: @KeyurPanchal Sorry, the right is "segunda.limite - NEW.valor".  *Did the correction on the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `CURSOR` for this. You can try the following trigger code. I hope this will fix your issue.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_primeira_UPD 
AFTER UPDATE ON primeira FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
   DECLARE v_limite_diff INT;
   DECLARE v_seg_id INT;
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT (s.limite - NEW.valor), s.id
     FROM segunda s WHERE s.ID_primeira = New.ID;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   OPEN c1; 
   my_loop: LOOP
     FETCH c1 INTO v_limite_diff, v_seg_id;
     IF done THEN
       LEAVE my_loop;
     END IF;
     IF( v_limite_diff < 50 ) THEN
       INSERT INTO terceira(ID_segunda) VALUES(v_seg_id);
     END IF;
   END LOOP;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Got an error: "Result consisted of more than one row".